# Convert single string which has an array of individual mixed data types

Tags: go

How to convert the single string which has an array of individual strings in it.

```
func main() {
  stringArrayInString := "[\"Hello\",\"Hai\",\"How are you!\"]" //Single string which has string array in it
    fmt.Println(stringArrayInString)

 // code to convert to the string array
 // convertedString
}
```

The output has to be like this

```
convertedString[0] = "Hello"
convertedString[1] = "Hai"
convertedString[2] = "How are you!"
```

Is this possible if the above input string has mixed data types such as int, string, JSON type
For example

```
stringArrayInString := "[\"Hello\",\"{\"msg\":\"Hai\"}\",123]"

//after converting

convertedString[0] = "Hello"
convertedString[1] = "{\"msg\":\"Hai\"}"
convertedString[2] = 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string array you have is a valid JSON array, so you can do this:

```
var convertedString []string
json.Unmarshal([]byte(str),&convertedString)
```

If you have multiple data types in that array, you can do that with a string array, you need an interface{} array:

```
var convertedData []interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(str),&convertedData)
```

Then you need to check types of individual elements in that array to find out what they are.

Comment: `stringArrayInString := "[\"Hello\",\"{\"msg\":\"Hai\"}\",123]"
var convertedData []interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(stringArrayInString),&convertedData)
fmt.Println(convertedData)` I am getting an empty array as output =>[]

Comment: @VenkateshSorapalli  The string in the question and previous comment are not valid JSON.  Are the strings intended to be JSON, or are they in some other format?

Comment: JSON in the string format., it is intended to be string convertedString[1] = "{\"msg\":\"Hai\"}"

Comment: The second element isn't valid json. You can use json unmarshal if you escape those quotes: [\"Hello\",\"{\\\"msg\\\":\\\"Hai\\\"}\",123]"

Comment: Is there any JS conversion method from `\"{\"msg\":\"Hai\"}\"` to `\"{\\\"msg\\\":\\\"Hai\\\"}\"`

Comment: @VenkateshSorapalli do you have control over how the string is constructed? For example why aren't you using raw strings to make your life easier? Or if you want to use normal string just remove the surrounding quotes around that object.